# Control the Music by Arduino and Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to control my iPhone Music Player by an arduino - has anyone experience with that?

At the moment I have an RedBearLab Low Energy Bluetooth Shield and a Ethernet Arduino here.

Maybe one of you has done this before and can help.